# How can I call a webpack file from another webpack file

Tags: webpack

I am including grapejs into a laravel project. In my webpack file I would like to to call the grapejs webpack file to build it freshly and then include it into my assets.

There is a dist JS file delivered with grapejs but I do not want to use that one, due to [security reasons](https://hackernoon.com/im-harvesting-credit-card-numbers-and-passwords-from-your-site-here-s-how-9a8cb347c5b5).

How can I call the grapejs webpack file which resides in my node_modules folder?

Comment: If you're using npm at all, you're already vulnerable to malicious or compromised publishers.  Avoiding one particular file doesn't really help.

Comment: That article was satirical. It's a "what if" scenario. It didn't really happen (yet hehe)